# FormatException in String.Format

Tags: c#

I am trying to learn about String.Format but it keeps throwing a FormatException.

Can anyone point me to my mistake?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var d = new DateTime(2016,5,10);
    var p = "Trumph";

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Mr. {1} will be elected as president on {2}", p, d));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: You need to use `{0}`and `{1}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The indices in a format string are 0-based.

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Mr. {1} will be elected as president on {2}", p, d));
```

So you are trying to access the second and third format arguments (the third and fourth argument to the `Format` call).

But you only specified two arguments. So change your format string to:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Mr. {0} will be elected as president on {1}", p, d));
```

and it should work.

---

Note that they gave us [*string interpolation*](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) with C# 6, so now you can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Mr. {p} will be elected as president on {d}");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Mr. {0} will be elected as president on {1}", p, d));
```

Have a look at [C# string.Format Method](http://www.dotnetperls.com/format)